# SQL Statement to Compare rows

Tags: sql, join, compare

I've got a table that stores Product #s, Client Name, and Region. So I can query for all products for a particular client in a specific region using this one  single table.

I'm trying to write a query that will allow me to see which products the client has in 1 region but not the other and vise-versa (compare regions). In other words, can I see all products in the north not in the south, and all products in the south not in the north, for a particular client.

I'm pretty sure this would be very easy if it were 2 separate queries, but I'm trying to do it in a single query. Is it possible?

```
Product          Client          Region
500              1               North
500              1               South
501              1               North
502              1               South
503              1               North
503              1               South
```

Results for the above data would indicate that Client 1 has Product 501 in the North, but not the South as well as Product 502 in the South but not the North. Products 500 and 503 are ignored since they're in both Regions.

```
Product          Client          Region
501              1               North
502              1               South
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like `ORDER BY region`?  I'm not sure how you are thinking you can display and hide data in a single query.

Comment: What database platform are you using?

Comment: @dugas shouldn't matter in this case as there are several answers that work in all of the major products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
Select product, client, region
From yourTable t
Where region in('north','south')
  And not exists(
    Select product, client, region
    From yourTable tt
    Where t.region <> tt.region
      And t.client = tt.client
      And t.product = tt.product
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

If a client has a product in both regions, then there are two rows (assuming no duplicates).  If there is a product in only one region, then the count is one.

So, the following query should return what you want:

```
select product, client, MAX(region) as region
from pcr
group by product, client
having COUNT(*) = 1
```

Comment: I think this is the simplest (and possibly best) answer.  I held off posting it because a couple of the other responders were close and I thought that they might correct their answers to this.

Answer (score 1):

I've tested the below code on a table I built based on the information you provided in your question. I've selected a group of products where the region column contains both `North` *and* `South`; from here I've taken the data from the result set where the `Product` does not appear (meaning it did not contain both `North` and `South`.

**The result:**

```
product     client      Region  
501         1           North   
502         1           South
```

**The query:**

```
SELECT * 
FROM   test 
WHERE  product NOT IN(SELECT t1.product 
                      FROM   test t1 
                             INNER JOIN test t2 
                                     ON t1.product = t2.product 
                      WHERE  t1.region = "North" 
                             AND t2.region = "South")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about WHICH region, the following shhould work, at least in mysql which lets you abuse group by a bit.

```
select product, client, count(*) cnt from blah where cnt = 1 group by product, client
```

Comment: The sample output does have region in it.  With some changes this query could both satisfy that need and be compatible with most SQL products.

Answer (score 0):

If using MSSQL > 2005, this should work for you:

```
SELECT pvt.Product, pvt.Client, [NORTH],[SOUTH]
FROM
(SELECT Product, Client, Region
FROM ProductTable) p
PIVOT
(
COUNT (Region)
FOR Region IN([NORTH],[SOUTH])
) pvt
WHERE ([NORTH]+[SOUTH]) <> 2
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/05365/7/0)